# Fancy Box - how to refresh DIV on modal window onclosed

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I've searched high and low through this forum and thus far I don't see an answer. And, I think I beginning to lose my mind.

Could be I'm just missing it as I am NOT a programmer.
I am a visual designer that can usually install pre written code without to much
difficulty. And, indeed I have installed FancyBox and have it working well
except for one small problem which I desperately need help with.

I am working with a dynamically generated page written in ColdFusion.
Three divs on the page contain FancyBox links that open editing screens.
Once editing is complete and the user closes the FancyBox modal the changes
need to be reflected on the parent page.

Right, so I was able to find a solution that refreshes the entire page

'onClosed': function() {
parent.location.reload(true); }
});

How, oh how can I get just a single div to refresh "onClosed" as
apposed to the entire page??????

Answer (score 1):

There a a couple of ways to do that.

One way is to get the content of the div with a function. This function will preform an ajax-call to get the content, say the function is called getcontent(); your syntax will be something like `onClosed': function() { getcontent(); }`

A better way to do this is to get the edited content and push this in the div. say you set a variable text with the content after the save of the editor, after that you can push this variable into the div with `onClosed': function() { $('#divid').html(yourvar); }`

I must say both ways are not easy to implement. Maybe if you show the code you currently having we can help you some more.

Comment: Right on Tim, well Fancybox uses jquery and loads it's own "library".

Each link that invokes fancybox has an id which is referred to like thus see the code below

Comment: The Id of the link does not have to be the id of content-div, so your answer doesn't make any sense. You must know in which div the text must be published, currently you only know which link activated the fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

Right on Tim, well Fancybox uses jquery and loads it's own "library".

Each link that invokes fancybox has an id which is referred to like thus

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#link1").fancybox({
'titleShow'     : false,
'width'             : '80%',
'height'            : '80%',
'autoScale'         : false,
'transitionIn'      : 'none',
'transitionOut'     : 'none',
'type'              : 'iframe',
'onClosed': function() {
   parent.location.reload(true); }
            });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add this additional information.  The "Your Answer" box is only for posting answers, not comments or edits.